# Finding class via string

Tags: python

```
import random

class Game():
    def __init__(self, username, gameId):
        self.users = []
        self.users.append(str(username))
        self.gameId = gameId

    def new_user(self, username):
        self.users.append(str(username))

    def remove_user(self, username):
        try:
            self.users.remove(username)
        except:
            print("[-] User not found!")

def generate_gameId(): 
    gameId = ""
    letters = 5
    while(letters>0):
        gameId += chr(random.randint(65, 90))
        letters-=1

    return(gameId)

lobby = []

for i in range(2):
    lobby.append(generate_gameId())
    lobby[i] = Game("Test", lobby[i])
    lobby[i].new_user("Test123")
    lobby[i].remove_user("Test123")
```

This is my code for a simple networking game, I will have multiple Game classes at the same time, but I need to find the specific object of a specific gameId. The gameId is randomly generated. Each time a user wants to join the lobby he has to enter the gameId to enter.

**How would you achieve something like this? Am I doing it wrong?**

Comment: Create a `dict` and each time you create a `Game` do `mydict[game_id] = game`.  The dict could be a global variable, a class-level attribute of `Game` or a separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things that can be refactored in your code:

- In the constructor of your `Game` class, there's no need for a `username` parameter, since there's already a `new_user` method:

```py
class Game():
    def __init__(self, gameId):
        # Just create the list of users
        self.users = []
        self.gameId = gameId

# ...

lobby = []
for i in range(2):
    lobby.append(generate_gameId())
    lobby[i] = Game(lobby[i])

    # Use the `new_user` method to create a Test
    lobby[i].new_user("Test")
    lobby[i].new_user("Test123")
    lobby[i].remove_user("Test123")
```

- You're storing the ids in an integer list. You should use a dictionary given that a game will have an unique id:

```py
lobby = {}
for i in range(2):
    game_id = generate_gameId()
    game = Game(game_id)

    # Create a entry in the dictionary
    lobby[game_id] = game
    
    game.new_user("Test")
    game.new_user("Test123")
    game.remove_user("Test123")
```

Then, you can access the list of games and their ids:

```
for game_id, game in lobby.items():
    print(f'The game {game_id} has the following users:')
    for user in game.users:
        print(user)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot, have a nice day. ^^

Answer (score 0):

The other guys said everything I was going to say so I deleted most of my post, but here's some other things you could improve on if you want:

1. You are not looking up a "Class" here. You're looking up an instance of a class, otherwise known as an object. The word "class" in programming always means "The definition of an object". Classes can be instantiated to make objects AKA instances. A good analogy is that a "class" is the blueprints for making a car, while the instance/object would be the car itself that was made using the blueprints(the class).
2. Don't combine naming conventions. You're combining camel case and snake case which is never a good idea, choose one or the other (python is usually snake case). Specifically, `generate_gameId()` should be `generate_game_id()`. This just makes it easier to write code without making spelling mistakes.